# How to access component state inside navigation options in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to access my component state inside navigationOptions. I tried to assign it to params inside componentDidMount. Still it didn't work. How can I set, this.state.SearchText as the value of the input which is inside navigationOptions?

```
export default class WorkoutScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchText: "Test Text"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      searchWorkouts: this.searchWorkoutHandler
    });
  }

  onChangeSearch = value => {
    this.setState({
      searchText: value
    });
  };

  searchWorkoutHandler = () => {
    alert("Searching Workouts");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.searchInput}>{this.state.searchText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    alert(params.searchText);

    return {
      headerTitle: (
        <SearchInput
          style={styles.searchInput}
          value={params.searchText}
          source={Search}
          borderRadius={50}
          placeholder="Search / Filter"
          onChangeText={value => this.onChangeSearch(value)}
          onPress={() => params.searchWorkouts()}
        />
      ),
      headerTitleStyle: { width: "100%", alignItems: "center" },
      headerStyle: {
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingLeft: 10
      },
      headerLeft: (
        <ClickableIcon
          source={Bookmark}
          onIconPressed={() => alert("Notifications Clicked Workout")}
        />
      ),
      headerRight: (
        <ClickableIcon
          source={Movements}
          onIconPressed={() => alert("Add New Clicked")}
        />
      )
    };
  };
}
```

Is there any standard way that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'd need to call `this.props.navigation.setParams` whenever the state changes to update the `params` value in `navigationOptions`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
    searchWorkouts: this.searchWorkoutHandler,
    searchText: this.state.searchText,
  });
}

onChangeSearch = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    searchText: value,
  });
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
    searchText: value,
  });
};
```

Comment: for me params is not updating . Please answer .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167422/access-component-state-inside-navigationoptions-react-native

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {
  notifyCont: 4
};

headerRight: (
      <Text style={{fontSize: 10}}>{navigation.getParam('number')}</Text>
  </View>
),
```

componentDidMount

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
  number: this.state.notifyCont,
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.