# Access Component state inside NavigationOptions - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I was trying to conditionally render HeaderLeft by state value, I cant able to access state value inside NavigationOptions

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({



    headerLeft: (navigation.state.searchText)? <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
           // navigation.navigate('home');
           alert('Coming soon ');
        }}>
            <Image style={{ marginLeft: 20,height:20,width:20,resizeMode:"contain" }} source={require('../assets/header_icons/three_logo.png')} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> : <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
   // navigation.navigate('home');
   alert('Coming soon');
}}>
    <Image style={{ marginLeft: 20,height:20,width:20,resizeMode:"contain" }} source={require('../assets/header_icons/icon_arrow_left.png')} />
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>

});
```

My component did mount

```
  componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({threebool:true});
  this.props.navigation.setParams({

    searchText: this.state.threebool,
  });
}
```

My constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    threebool:true,

  }
}
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: You should be using `navigation.state.params.searchText` not `navigation.state.searchText`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236254/how-to-access-component-state-inside-navigation-options-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is static, that`s why it doens't access state.
if you want your navigator to update with your state you need to call setparams everytime you update state. I would create a function to update state and call setparams to it easier.

```
updateNavAndState(bool){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        searchText: bool,
      });
    this.setState({threebool:bool})
}
```

Comment: how to call this method from navigationOptions

Comment: To update the navigation option params you can simply call ()=>navigation.setParams({searchTextl:bool})

Comment: To call my entire function you have to pass it to the navigationOptions through navigations at componentWillMount(){
this.props.navigation.setParams({
      updateNavAndState: this.updateNavAndState 
})

if this doesnt work you have to bind the function at constructor

Comment: and then call it inside navigator          static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
return{
    headerLeft: <Button onPress={()=>params.updateNavAndState} title='update'/>}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
  handleSubmit: this.handleSubmit,
  state: this.state;
});
handleSubmit = () => {}
```

in navigation option you will get values by

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation = this.props.navigation }) => {
const state = navigation.state.params.state;
const handleSubmit = navigation.state.params.handleSubmit;}
```